# Orthocenter of a Triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

Given an Isosceles triangle where in the altitude to the base is divided into lengths 7 and 9 by the orthocenter, what are the sides of the triangle.

I solved this using coordinate geometry using perpendicular lines for the slopes and such. the answer is that the legs are 20 and the base is 24.

I want to know another approach where in we do not use coordinate geometry, I have tried using similar triangles, using the orthocenter but I am stuck, I am thinking that we would use a property (?) of an orthocenter that I have ignored

from ITMO national parallel cluster, Philippines (does not affect the actual ITMO) awards have already been given out.

Comment: do you know Menelaus's theorem? you could use that (apply to the left half, with the altitude towards the left leg as the line)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $|AB|=c$, $\angle C_hCA=\tfrac\gamma2$.

$\triangle C_hCA$
is similar to 
$\triangle C_hAO_h$,

\begin{align} 
\angle C_hCA&=\angle C_hAO_h=\tfrac\gamma2
,\\
\triangle AC_hC:\quad
\tan\tfrac\gamma2&=\frac{c/2}{16}=\frac{c}{32}
,\\
\triangle O_hC_hA:\quad
\tan\tfrac\gamma2&=\frac{9}{c/2}=\frac{18}{c}
,\\
\frac{18}c&=\frac{c}{32}
,\\
c&=24
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider $A,B,C$ to be vertices $E,F,G$ the respective perpendicular points to the vertices and $O$ the orthocenter. Notice $AOF$ is similar to $ACE$ and using this information you can find the lengths